# Database login incorrect

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having some trouble with some software that I'm tweaking. During my install script I can type my database username, database name, localhost, etc and once I click next it is suppose to connect to the database and start the install. However when I click next I have shown this error:

> Database Login Incorrect: config.php

Here is my config.php file:

```
<?php

// Mysql Settings
  $mysqli_host      = "";
  $mysqli_login     = "";
  $mysqli_pass      = "";
  $mysqli_database  = "";
  $db_prefix            = "";

  $_dbConn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_login, $mysqli_pass)
  or die ('Database Login Incorrect: config.php');

  mysqli_select_db($mysqli_database, $_dbConn)
  or die ('Unable to select the database: config.php');

?>
```

Although the database name and username are correct and have proper permissions. I can show the install file but it is over 2k lines and didn't want to post all of that :p

Thanks for your time!

Edit:

After using Geo V L's fix, I now have the error of "have you run install.php yet?". This is located in my structure.php file:

```
// Include functions...

    include "scripts/php/functions.php";

// get board theme

    $query2     =   "select THEME from {$db_prefix}settings";
    $result2    =   mysqli_query($query2) or die("Have you run install.php yet?");                                  
    $theme      =   mysqli_result($result2, 0);
```

Comment: are you sure your mySql setting already correct?

Comment: can you please modify your die to **die (mysql_error())** and paste error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippent $_dbConn will be the first parameter for  mysqli_select_db

```
    <?php

// Mysql Settings
  $mysqli_host      = "";
  $mysqli_login     = "";
  $mysqli_pass      = "";
  $mysqli_database  = "";
  $db_prefix            = "";

  $_dbConn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_login, $mysqli_pass)
  or die ('Database Login Incorrect: config.php');

  mysqli_select_db( $_dbConn,$mysqli_database)
  or die ('Unable to select the database: config.php');

?>
```

Or you can directly add databasename on mysqli connect string like the following

```
    <?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_login, $mysqli_pass, $mysqli_database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Added response to my original question ^